# VBA: Handling PowerPivot refreshing error

Tags: vba, excel, powerpivot

I'm using a Macro to refresh some data in PowerPivot, it then autosaves the updated file on my computer.
My problem is that I'm using SSH in order to connect to a database and due to bad connection sometimes it crashes and stop the refreshing process. Then powerpivot can't refresh the worksheet but my macro keep being executed as if nothing happened...

I'd like to know if there is a way to handle in VBA such an error in order to loop the refreshing process until it is fully and properly executed.

Comment: Have you checked out error handling in VBA? [Error Handling in Macros](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/141571)

Comment: Thanks I'll try it this afternoon I'll keep you guys posted with any news so it can help other people on my case :)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and most straight forward way I would suggest is to use a boolean variable and assign in to yes if the powerPivot gets refreshed properly and false if it doesn't. Thus only when the variable is true the macro will run. An example is:

```
  Dim result As Boolean

  result = False

  if PowerPivot gets refreshed then
      'the refesh code
       result = true
  end if 


  if result = true then
     'run the macro code
  end if
```

Thus only when powerpivot is fully refreshed the macro will run. Otherwise not.